# how to mark a portion of a TextField as readonly in javafx?

Tags: javafx

i wanted to mark a part of the `TextField` as readonly.
Is it possible to do in JavaFX?
Basically for a xml editor i want to make xml tags values to be editable but not the tags itself.
So wanted to know how to make the a part of the `TextField` as readonly.

Comment: Do you mean `TextArea`? Having said that, as far as I'm aware there's nothing built in on the `TextField` or `TextArea` classes that will let you do this directly. You might have to place a listener on the text property, detect each change then decide whether or not to "allow" it within that listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mark as readonly, but as [@berry120](https://stackoverflow.com/users/551406/berry120) suggested isn't hard to enforce it with listeners:

**Main.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


    public class Main extends Application{
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            TagField tf = new TagField("find","nemo");
            Pane root = new Pane();
            root.getChildren().add(tf);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        public static void main(String[] args){launch(args);  }
    }
```

**TagField.java**

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class TagField extends TextField{
    String initTag;
    String closeTag;
    public TagField(String tag,String text){
        this.initTag = "<" + tag + ">";
        this.closeTag = "</" + tag + ">";
        setTagText(initTag + text + closeTag);
        super.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>(){
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                if(!newValue.contains(initTag)||!newValue.contains(closeTag)){
                    setTagText(oldValue);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public void setTagText(String text){
        super.setText(text);
    }
}
```

[This code is available on gist](https://gist.github.com/kyllopardiun/2459466c3be938a52e31)

And the idea would be analog with the `TextArea`